# using ckan web content how can I sum values from numeric column using sql with group by

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery, ckan

Getting error message: Conflict as result from this connection using Power BI Power Query

```
let  Fonte = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT " & """DscClasseConsumo"", ""CodClasseConsumo""," & """sum(MdaPotenciaInstaladaKW)""" & " from ""b1bd71e7-d0ad-4214-9053-cbd58e9564a7""" & "group by ""DscClasseConsumo"" ,""CodClasseConsumo""")),
#"Convertido para Tabela" = Table.FromRecords({Fonte}),
#"result Expandido" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Convertido para Tabela", "result", {"sql", "records", "fields"}, {"result.sql", "result.records", "result.fields"})
in
#"result Expandido"
```

Answer (score 0):

your code evaluates as

```
https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT "DscClasseConsumo", "CodClasseConsumo","sum(MdaPotenciaInstaladaKW)" from "b1bd71e7-d0ad-4214-9053-cbd58e9564a7"group by "DscClasseConsumo" ,"CodClasseConsumo"
```

if you did this query manually, what would you use, and how does it compare

Comment: I did the query using JSON connection editor in PowerBI

Comment: The query you suggested matches with what I'm trying to do, but the "sum" function is not in the correct synthax or not supported by web.contents

Comment: I have not suggested a query, that is the query you used.  There is no sum function in powerquery, does SQL have one?